# How to bin data to remove low counts?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to treat data using binning for privacy preserving purposes. The data involves numerical integers and must be binned in such a way that the frequencies are above a minimum value, `x`.

I would also like to minimise the width of bins to preserve the data as much as possible. Minimising the width of bins is not strictly defined because this is just a general aim to avoid unnecessary data loss. Since the distribution of the integers vary, the bin sizes will be *non-uniform*.

I am hoping to develop a function that can take a set of integers `data$column` and a minimum count threshold `x`, and return a set of treated integers `data$treated_column`.

This is an example where the minimum count threshold is 3 which shows counts before and after treatment.

```
set.seed(10)
data <- tibble(column = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE))
data %>% count(column)
expected_data <- data %>% mutate(treated_column = c('3-5','1-2','1-2','3-5','3-5','1-2','1-2','1-2','3-5','3-5'))
expected_data %>% count(treated_column)
```

These are two additional data columns which more closely reflect the type of data I am actually working with which can be used as examples.

```
set.seed(5)
data <- tibble(columnA = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE),
               columnB = sample(10:1000, 1000, replace = TRUE))
```

The type of logic I have been thinking through is something like this but I can't figure out how to implement:

1. Count integer frequency and arrange by ascending integer
2. If count >=`x` in first row, keep same. If count <`x`, combine with next integer successively until count >=`x`
3. Iterate through remaining rows
4. Check if last bin has count >=x, if not then combine last 2 bins
5. Create treated_column with binned results

Comment: Can you clarify a bit please - are you expecting code to automatically set the bins, or are you happy to set them and have the code do the binning?  Can you provide the logic or pseudocode for how you'd do the binning if you were doing it manually, for a small example?

Comment: Thanks @Paul. I have tried to clarify further in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive function that splits into groups that are never smaller than `min_size` (but is greedy and does not guarantee more groups cannot be created):

```
recursive_mingrp <- function(x, min_size = 6L) {
 # Recursive helper function 
 find_grps <- \(x) {
   low <- which(x < median(unique(x)))
   if (length(unique(x)) == 1L || length(low) < min_size || length(x)-length(low) < min_size) {
     limits[length(limits) + 1L] <<- max(x)    
     return(NULL)
   }
   find_grps(x[low])
   find_grps(x[-low])
 }
 
 x      <- sort(x)
 limits <- list()
 find_grps(x)
 if (length(limits) == 1L) limits <- range(x)
 cut(x, unlist(limits), include.lowest=T) 
}
```

Example

```
set.seed(10)
table(recursive_mingrp(sample(10:1000, 1000, replace = TRUE), 33))
  #  [66,123]   (123,191]   (191,258]   (258,329]   (329,388]   (388,448]   (448,519] 
  #        67          63          58          65          59          58          61 
  # (519,582]   (582,609]   (609,636]   (636,686]   (686,716]   (716,748]   (748,809] 
  #        62          34          33          71          33          40          58 
  # (809,883]   (883,940] (940,1e+03] 
  #        59          60          58
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach I took was to group by the column in question, then for each row that doesn't have enough members, keep adding the count of the next row (and then the next row, and so on), until we reach the minimum group size.

```
library(tidyverse)

anonymiser <- function(df, col, group) {
  col_string <- quo_name(enquo(col))
  # create a dataframe grouped by the grouping column
  groups <- df %>% 
    group_by({{col}}) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    
    # add a row number column, and a bin start and bin end column
    # if the count for the group is already larger than or equal to the 
    # minimum group size, then we add those as the bin start and bin end
    # otherwise we add NA
    mutate(row = row_number(), 
           bin_start := {{col}},
           bin_end = ifelse(count >= group, {{col}}, NA))
  bad_rows <- groups[is.na(groups$bin_end),]$row
  
  # for every row with less than the minimum group size
  while (length(bad_rows) > 0) {
    i = bad_rows[1]
    # remove the row from the vector of bad rows
    bad_rows <- bad_rows[-1]
    
    # we go through the following rows, adding the counts of those rows, until we pass the minimum group size threshold
    nxt = i
    new_count = groups[i,]$count
    while (new_count < group) {
      nxt <- nxt + 1
      new_count = new_count + groups[nxt,]$count
      
      # if one of the rows we find is also in bad rows, we can remove that one too
      if (nxt %in% bad_rows) {
        bad_rows <- bad_rows[bad_rows != nxt]
      }
      
    }
    # set the bin end variable to the last row we added
    end <- groups[nxt,] %>% pull({{col}})
    
    # update the bin start and bin end of every row we passed
    for (j in i:nxt) {
      groups[j,]$bin_start = groups[i,]$bin_start
      groups[j,]$bin_end = end
    }
  }
  df %>% 
    left_join(groups, by = col_string) %>% 
    mutate(bin = paste0(bin_start, "-", bin_end)) %>% 
    select(-count, -row, -bin_start, -bin_end)
}

anonymiser(data, columnA, 10)

# A tibble: 1,000 × 3
   columnA columnB bin  
     <int>   <int> <chr>
 1      66     272 65-66
 2      57     904 57-57
 3      79     705 79-79
 4      75     865 75-76
 5      41     927 41-41
 6      85      44 85-85
 7      94      25 93-94
 8      71     449 71-71
 9      19     915 19-20
10       3     414 2-3  
# ℹ 990 more rows

# unimplemented ideas:
# * option of going downwards instead
# * check for the last row in the dataframe being too small
# * binning multiple columns in one function call
# feedback/ideas/edits welcome!
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution but when I use `anonymiser(data, columnB, 6)` I get an error. Will think through your solution to see if I can figure out why.

Comment: I just did a bit of debugging- it turns out the problem that I thought would be relatively rare turned up on the first example you tried . I'll debug it tomorrow morning!

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I haven’t been able to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to do the binning in such a way that each cell contains approximately the same number of data points. This can be done with `quantile`. Example:

```
> breaks <- quantile(iris$Sepal.Length, (1:10)/10)
> table(cut(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks=breaks, include.lowest=T))
   [4.8,5]   (5,5.27] (5.27,5.6]  (5.6,5.8]  (5.8,6.1]  (6.1,6.3] (6.3,6.52] 
        21         13         20         15         15         13         12 
(6.52,6.9]  (6.9,7.9] 
        17         13
```

If you do not like small bin sizes, you can start from this binning and use a hierarchical clustering to merge adjacent bins that have a small width. Hierarchical clustering requires a distance measure, which would be in this case infinite for non adjacent cells, and the width of the merged cells for neighboring cells.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion - issue with this is that you would have to vary the number of quantiles each time you used on a different column of data.

Comment: @Mark "different columns of data"? Different columns all have the same number of items (rows) in a data.frame, so I do not understand what you mean. Moreover, you can automatically compute the number of cells from the intended number of items per cell and the number of rows in your data.frame.

Comment: In my sample data there are two columns with different min/max values. I would need to change the number of quantiles for each of these to get a result that minimises bin width whilst maintaining the minimum count of 6. In the example you provided from iris, the number of quantiles would be 14 to give the minimum bin width, but this would change for every set of data.

Comment: @Mark I still do not understand what you are looking for. You have *two* dimensional data, but are looking for *one* dimensional cells? Please clarify your quesiton and provide an example of teh expected result.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I have tried to clarify again in the question