# Automatically splitting a data frame in dplyr based on number of rows and another column's condition

Tags: r, function, performance, dplyr, split

I Have a dataset that has more than **150,000 rows** of data and also contains **15 columns**. For the sake of size, I need to **automatically** break it down and write it into smaller pieces of **csv** based on two conditions:

1. The number of rows for each file should be **4** unless the last dataset that could have  less rows.
2. Each file should possibly have the maximum number of rows lined to an id and not let the rows of one id be distributed randomly across all files.

please note that there are not more than **4** rows of data assigned to each id
Also, the smaller data frames should have an **order and date index**

an snapshot of the data is as follows:

```
id=c(1,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3)
letter=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k")
df <- data.frame(id,letter)
```

`df %>% arrange(id)`

```
1   1      a
2   1      b
3   1      d
4   2      c
5   2      e
6   2      j
7   3      f
8   3      k
9   4      g
10  5      h
11  6      i
```

So the output of interest in this example should be something like these ones:

**df_20230704_1**

```
  id letter
1  1      a
2  1      b
3  1      d
4  4      g
```

**df_20230704_2**

```
  id letter
1  2      c
2  2      e
3  4      g
4  2      j
```

**df_20230704_3**

```
  id letter
1  3      f
2  5      h
3  6      i
4  3      k
```

Comment: So the number of rows in each CSV has to be **at least** 4? Maybe you can use a solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76611478/how-to-bin-data-to-remove-low-counts/76613723#76613723 ?

Comment: thanks, it has to be chunks of 4 unless the last chunk that may be less.

Comment: So one id can appear in many files?

Comment: these is maximum 4 rows linked to an id, so they all must be captured in one dataset, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be hard to do it just using `dplyr`. You could start by looking at `group_split` function.

With the output you can try to combine the data frames to have 4 rows each

Comment: This is not even close to the problem at hand. The question contains replicates